# Does an end user (or CA) certificate have any "fingerprinting" to indicate the brand of PKI being used?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, forensics, certificate-revocation

As part of my forensics, I want to determine if a given certificate has any indicator of which PKI software was used to create it.

So far, I see differences in the following properties for a Certificate Authority:

- Serial Number (format, length, is ( not) random)
- Issuer value (may align with internal AD forest name in MSFT)
- Presence of "Certificate Template Information" (MSFT)
- CRL Distribution Point contains a server name
- Subject contains "DC = " (MSFT) versus other properties such as `O`, `C` present in Google.com

I'm sure there are comparable differences in end entity certificates, and CRL/CRL Dif certificates.

**Question**

- Is there any resource that investigates the differences between the certificate output from various CA's  (or makecert.exe for that matter)?
- Is there any byte level fingerprinting within a certificate? (or is everything exposed via a certificate export?

Comment: I can't find the @#$! reference right now, but part of the recent mess with WoSign and Startcom involved Startcom switching to WoSign server software, without notifying anyone, after being silently acquired.  The connection to this question being, the fact that they switched servers was detected by changes in the nuances of how requests were signed.  So, yes, fingerprinting may be possible.

Comment: Within the cert data? I don't know. But there is something like this for RSA pubkeys: From Usenix Sec 2016: [*The Million-Key Question—Investigating the Origins of RSA Public Keys*](https://crocs.fi.muni.cz/public/papers/usenix2016) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/LOUvl).)

Comment: @gowenfawr: Do you mean Gervase Markham's 2016-10-18 report? He writes: *These templates and systems can have “fingerprints”, such as particular extensions, fixed fields, ways of doing things or even encoding errors, which allow you to work out which template was in use.* And later on: [*However, there is technical evidence that around a month and a half after the acquisition, StartCom issuances switched to using WoSign’s infrastructure - either the same instance of it, or their own instance.*](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C6BlmbeQfn4a9zydVi2UvjBGv6szuSB4sMYUcVrR8vQ/edit)

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff that's exactly it, thank you, it was the bit about 'quirks of serial numbers' that I was remembering.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but maybe hints in the right direction

#### Cert linters

These might be interesting to spot anomalies: There is Peter Bowen's certlint (written in Ruby) and Kurt Roeckx's x509lint. Both of these are integrated into crt.sh. Here are some examples with interesting anomalies: [cert for *.gmaptiles.co.kr](https://crt.sh/?id=38667760&opt=cablint,x509lint) and [example.com](https://crt.sh/?id=24564717&opt=cablint,x509lint)

Also there is another certlint: [GlobalSign's certlint (written in Go)](https://github.com/globalsign/certlint). I haven't tried that.

#### Pubkey generator identification

Also: There is some research on how to detect the library used to generate RSA pubkeys: From Usenix Sec 2016: [*The Million-Key Question—Investigating the Origins of RSA Public Keys*](https://crocs.fi.muni.cz/public/papers/usenix2016) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/LOUvl).)